# Text colour highlighting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
//<![CDATA[
var blinkText = $(".highlight");

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  blinkText.toggleClass("highlightRed");
}, 500);
//]]>
```

```css
.highlight {
  -webkit-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
.highlightRed {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="highlight" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 33px; color: #00F">&rarr;</span>
```

[**JSFiddle:**](https://jsfiddle.net/o1owo30u/)

The above code is expected to make the given arrow blink according to the interval given but it does not. How to make the arrow change colour with respect to the interval given?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/o1owo30u/2/

Comment: did you add jquery? when i added jquery in the fiddle, it works perfectly.

Comment: It does not function in a server based application. A jQuery library has been added to the application and is available on the browser. There is no error on the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change following things to make your code work.

1. Attach `jQuery` to your web page.
2. Use your JavaScript code in inside `$(function() { ... });` code so that it founds elements in `DOM`
3. Move your inline styles to the stylesheet attached.
4. Styles of `highlightRed` class should come after styles of `.highlight` in stylesheet.

***Note: no need to use `!important` in your styles. It should be avoided as much as possible.***

```js
$(function() {
  var blinkText = $(".highlight");

  var interval = setInterval(function () {
      blinkText.toggleClass("highlightRed");
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    -webkit-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #00F;
}

.highlightRed {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="highlight">&rarr;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add !important in color:red:

```
.highlightRed {
    color: red !important;
}
```

OR

IF you dont want to use !important, as !important id not a good practise just do it:

1) Remove inline css from span and add that style into any class called custom:

```
<span class="highlight custom">&rarr;</span>

.custom {
   font-weight: bolder; font-size: 33px; color: #00F;
}
```

2)   Define highlightRed css class like this:

```
span.highlightRed {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.highlightRed {
    color: red !important;
}
```